# AWGs for the following LED setup

Tags: led, amperage, led-strip, awg

I'm ass deep in my next project.....4 LED cubes(small lanterns) on the ceiling...

The strip is:

**Power: 0.1-0.4W/LED 6W-24W/m Total: 30W-120W This is a variable value**

Have a 12V power with enough AMPS.... they wiill be laid out on the ceilling in a square about 8ft between each "node"

There will be about 54 leds on each node...

What I'm not sure of is wire thickness...on an RGBW the pads are quite small.....

The run from the power to the first light will be about 14ft(corner of the layout) then of course there is back from each RGBW back to the ground...

i'm kinda scratching my head at wire size.....12V LEDs..

Comment: You could try math and get the current then use one of the handy lookup tables to convert current into AWG.

Comment: You might like to use this AWG chart: https://i.imgur.com/FN3NfGC.jpeg  Have a great project.  Cheers.

Comment: @Arsenal well at 120W that is 10AMPS but I'm not thiking I will ever get to tthat...all LEDs on full

Comment: @tlfong01 would my distances foollow chassis or power transmission? and why dooes it stop at 18AWG?

Comment: @BostonMacOSX Just curious. Since this is on the ceiling and there's very little risk, why not just run mains wiring (24 W total won't require a large gauge, at all) and use four separate AC-DC converters (not large, each, at 6 W apiece?) This way each cube is self-contained and easily tested. Running a 12 VDC line just seems like asking for more complex issues related to distribution of power.

Answer (score 0):

As you realized, the maximum current would be 10 A at 12 V.

According to the [engineering toolbox website](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wire-gauges-d_419.html) this would require a 16 AWG copper cable (two cores). But that's right at the edge, so I'd opt for a 14 AWG cable to have some reserve.

If you can ensure, that you never run at maximum power, you could use a smaller gauge, but I don't think 14 AWG is that massive.

You could also use a fitting cable between the cubes and increase the AWG the further on you get in your chain, so 14 AWG for the first cube, 16 AWG for the next and so on, but I don't really see a benefit there.

And for ease of installation use a stranded wire cable.